# How to integrate $I = \int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + b}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

$$I = \int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + b}}dx$$

I tried to integrate by parts but failed. I think I'm supposed to change variables using a hyperbolic sine, but I don't know this method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a,b>0$ we have:
$$ \int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+b}}=2\int_{0}^{\frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=2\operatorname{arcsinh}\frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}}=\log\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{-a+\sqrt{a^2+4b}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2$$
and
$$\cosh x=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}2$$
we have that
$$\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x=1$$

Assuming that $b>0$, write
$$\sqrt{x^2+b}=\sqrt b\cdot \sqrt{\left(\frac x{\sqrt b}\right)^2+1}$$

and now,
$$\frac x{\sqrt b}=\sinh t$$

Answer (score 1):

If $b=0$, then the problem is trivial.

If $b>0$, then you should take a look at the function $\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$ (hyperbolic arcsin, aka areasinus). Its derivative is equal to $1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$ (found in any reference book on derivatives/primitives).

If $b<0$, then you should take a look at $\ln(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x)$ (see comment above).